# Heroku error code=H10

Tags: node.js, heroku

I keep getting error `code=H10` randomly when I start my Heroku app. Sometimes the app starts, sometimes it doesn't.

My app is built with NodeJS, Express, MySQL and JawsDB.

Here's the details in my app's log:

```
2017-11-26T15:21:36.906937+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=<my app name>.herokuapp.com request_id=4c63d70d-f081-44a5-b4fe-f0992116ba79 fwd="108.28.184.177" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-26T15:21:36.954063+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=<my app name>.herokuapp.com request_id=e42d6293-512f-4ea1-ba35-403f44e4fd9a fwd="108.28.184.177" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I've looked online and added `favicon.ico` in my public folder. Nothing changes. I've had this problem before with my previous app and I ran `heroku restart` and it works for that one, but doesn't for this one.